# Is there a way to add items to an array in an xml file?

Tags: java, arrays, xml, android-studio, xml-formatting

I have an xml file e.g. "list.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="country_name">
  <item>Switzerland</item>
  <item>Iceland</item>
</array>

<array name="flag_url">
  <item>url1</item>
  <item>url2</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

Then in my MainActivity.java I do various things with them, but that is not the point here, is there a way I can do something like name.add("CountryName")?

The MainActivity.java:

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    TypedArray name = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.country_name);
    TypedArray flag = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.flag_url);
    //-----name.add(CountryName);----
```

So my list.xml would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <array name="country_name">
   <item>Switzerland</item>
   <item>Iceland</item>
   <item>CountryName</item>
</array>

<array name="flag_url">
   <item>url1</item>
   <item>url2</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

Comment: No, you can't. You you have to create an array programatically and then modify that one.

Comment: You might like to look at XSLT.